# Organize plugins and .vimrc settings for different filetypes using ftplugins?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, plugin-system, ftplugin

I'm new to vim (8.2) and have been learning how to set it up on my computer (Ubuntu 18) for the past few days.

I'd like to configure VIM so that when I open code in different programming languages, different settings load. Eg. indentation, color-theme, plugins etc.

I found `ftplugin` to be the recommended way to achieve this setup. Let's assume I want to setup VIM for python and markdown. I've installed the plugins (NERDTree, ale etc.) using VIM's native package manager. I've put some plugins like NERDTree in the `/start` folder while some like ALE in the `/opt` folder. This is because I want NERDTree to always load when I open any file using VIM while I want to conditionally load ALE when I only open a python file (and not markdown).

From what I've read in other answers and blogposts, we need to do the following -

1. Add `filetype plugin indent on` at the start of the main `~/.vimrc`.
2. Create folders `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` and `~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim`.

```
"file => ~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim
setlocal number
setlocal autoindent
setlocal shiftwidth=4
packadd! ale
```

```
"file => ~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim
setlocal number
setlocal autoindent
setlocal shiftwidth=2
```

Will this setup work? Any mistakes/gotchas in this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It sounds like you’ve already got a good handle on some confusing concepts, and I would love to write an answer to help you figure out the rest. However, we [really prefer not to have multiple distinct questions in one post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/389795). Would you please [edit] your question to scope it to one question? Feel free to ask the other questions as separate questions! For example: « What is the difference between ftplugin and after/ftplugin » and « What is b:undo_ftplugin used for » sound like good titles to me!

Comment: Once "refactored", I wonder if we don't already have Q/A's that address the _atomic_ questions.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I've refactored the question. Is this okay?

Comment: @LucHermitte most "atomic" questions here don't have answers with this context. As in they tell you what `/after/`, for instance, does but not how will that affect the following setup. That answer is probably helpful to experienced users but leave beginners like me kinda confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add filetype plugin indent on at the start of the main ~/.vimrc

Note that `filetype plugin indent on` is the default for Neovim; also it's in Vim's `defaults.vim`, so if you already have `runtime defaults.vim` (or vimrc is missing) you don't need it either. If you're unsure you can check the current setting by typing `:filetype` without any other parameters. If it's not yet here then add that line to your vimrc.

To elaborate on what it's really doing:

`filetype on` enables `:h 'filetype'` auto-detection by catching `BufRead`/`BufNew` events (within `augroup filetypedetect`) and analyzing buffer contents, or more often simply file extension. Note that setting `:h 'filetype'` also triggers `FileType` event for that buffer.

`filetype plugin on` enables filetype-based settings (mostly various buffer-local options) by catching `FileType` event (within `augroup filetypeplugin`). As `FileType` event is normally triggered by auto-detection routine, `filetype plugin on` also switches `filetype on` to save a few keystrokes.

`filetype indent on` is almost the same but it catches `FileType` event (within `augroup filetypeindent`) to install some custom indent-calculation procedure (typically by `:h 'indentexpr'`). As calculating indent on-the-fly is rather sophisticated procedure it was moved into a dedicated subplugin of its own and can be switched on or off independently of `ftplugin` thing.

Finally, `filetype plugin indent on` is a 3-in-1 command which enables all that ingredients.

Also, you might want to switch syntax highlighting on, so you'll probably need `syntax on` too. BTW. Although the syntax stuff has a command of its own, but ultimately it also depends on FileType event, and so `syntax on` also switches `filetype on` automatically.

> Create <s>folders</s> ~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim and ~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim.

When the code in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin.vim` receives `FileType` event it doesn't do anything there, but, for maximum flexibility, it sources all appropriate scripts to change the settings. Therefore, the effect depends on the order those scripts are sourced. It's all in `:set rtp?` - normally your `~/.vim` precedes `$VIMRUNTIME`, which in turn precedes `~/.vim/after`. And so if your settings are in `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` they may be (and will be) overwritten by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim` (in principle, you can add `let b:did_ftplugin=1` and skip all that standard "python" stuff altogether, but usually it's not recommended). For this reason you normally want `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` and not `~/.vim/ftplugin`.

> Any mistakes/gotchas in this?

Note that this code will be executed each time any buffer's `'filetype'` is set to "python" (or "markdown"). Hence, you'd better do only buffer-local initialization. A thing like `:packadd` is hardly suitable here.

Having said this, almost all plugins have guards against multiple initialization, and so it should not really matter; but, anyway, it looks ugly to me. So I'd rather do:

```
if !exists('g:loaded_ale')
    packadd ale
endif
```

This should at least save us from extra reading and parsing `plugin/ale.vim`. Also note that you misuse the "bang" in `:packadd` - read `:h :packadd` carefully.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! It's cleared up a lot of vim-black-magic for me! :) I have a follow-up question about the last part. What do you mean when you say `almost all plugins have guards against multiple initialization`? For instance, let's say I want NERDTree to be active when I open a python file, but not for a markdown file. Because I've installed NERDTree in `/opt`, I need to manually load it (either from inside VIM or vimrc). If `:packadd pkgname` is not suitable to be used in a `ftplugin`, then how do I go about loading NERDTree when required?

Comment: @theairbend3r Just put all plugins into `/start`, except ones used from time to time. Normally plugins are designed with autoload (i.e. "lazy-load") support. Don't overthink the things. Your best optimization is to remove the stuff you never use.

Comment: This simplifies things a lot. So, all plugins in `/start` is the way to go. `ftplugin` will contain different `.vim` files for each language which will contain general stuff (no `packadd`s).

Comment: @theairbend3r the only thinks I packadd are language plugins where I don’t have the language installed on all the machines I use with those dotfiles (and even then, it doesn’t hurt to let those be in start). Another example would be if you have a plugin for a tool; you could packadd it only if the tool is installed. But again, that’s more complex than usually necessary.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I see. Thanks for the examples! :)

Comment: A question about lazy loading. Let's say a plugin like ALE is installed in the `/start` dir. Assume ALE is available only for Python and not for markdown. So, when I open any file using VIM, ALE _loads lazily_? What does this mean? Because ALE is supposed to run asynchronously when a file is opened. Now, because it does not support markdown, it won't run. But if a python file is opened, ALE will start running? How is this lazy loading? Sorry for such basic question, still haven't been able to wrap my head around this.

Comment: @theairbend3r I think it should be really obvious that "plugin" mostly consists of a "code". And "code" is not a part of any buffer per se, yet it rather "hooks" into some "buffer"-related events. So it's more or less the same as it's with "ftdetect-ftplugin" thing. And you almost never need to unload anything as it's simply unpractical.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks! :)